# Proyecto JavaWeb funciona en local y da error en servidor

Tags: java, tomcat

Buen dia, paso por aquí para solicitar una ayuda especial.

He desarrollado un sistema de historias clinicas el cual lleva funcionando en producción desde hace ya un año. Resulta y pasa que en mi servidor local (desarrollo) todas las opciones funcionan correctamente, pero en el servidor de producción el registro de pacientes me tira error y no he encontrado forma de repararlo teniendo en cuenta que ese módulo no lo he tocado ya hace varias versiones atrás. Tampoco he encontrado la forma de capturar el error con un try-catch ya que no lo está capturando.

No encuentro ninguna logica en el hecho que en el servidor local funciona y en el servidor de producción no, y solo esa opción da error. Ya he reiniciado el tomcat, el servidor como tal, he actualizado Java, etc. y nada.

Me gustaría que me ayudaran  con tips o cosas que tal vez pueda revisar segun sus experiencias y a ver si de pronto a alguien ya le ha pasado.

En el servidor local y en producción corro Java 8 up 201 build 9 con tomcat 9.

Comment: ¿Que error tira?

Comment: Deberías añadir logs

Comment: como comenta Pablo, en los logs puedes encontrar más información relacionada a este problema.

Comment: Ese es el problema, que no tira ningun error capturable con el try-catch.
¿Como hago para agregar log?

Comment: Logré corregirlo reinstalando Java. Parece que era un problema de compatibilidad. Gracias a todos.